# Order a Matrix by the Values in One Column

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have a data set called `regional_regression`, as below.

```
regional_regression

$`East Asia & Pacific (all income levels)`
     (Intercept)       gdpcap 
48.180966940 -0.001276384 

$`Europe & Central Asia (all income levels)`
  (Intercept)        gdpcap 
28.8153087170 -0.0005021196 

$`Latin America & Caribbean (all income levels)`
 (Intercept)       gdpcap 
59.706105856 -0.003207999 

$`Middle East & North Africa (all income levels)`
  (Intercept)        gdpcap 
54.6225615193 -0.0008088255 

$`North America`
 (Intercept)       gdpcap 
32.444196028 -0.000599279 

$`South Asia`
 (Intercept)       gdpcap 
109.71477941  -0.02396868 

$`Sub-Saharan Africa (all income levels)`
  (Intercept)        gdpcap 
105.434754813  -0.006815668
```

I want to get this data in an orderly table, and sort by the column that will be called "Coefficient".

```
regional_regressional <- regional_regression %>% as.data.frame() 
regional_regression_table <- t(regional_regressional)
col_names <- c("Intercept", "Coefficient") 
colnames(regional_regression_table) <- col_names
```

Since it seems that I am dealing with a matrix, I keep getting errors when I've tried things like:

```
regional_regression_table[order(regional_regression_table$Coefficient),]

regional_regression_table[order(regional_regression_table[,"V2"]),]

setorder(regional_regression_table, -Coefficient)
```

Any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Coefficient is your second column in `matrix` then you just do the following. Since it is a `matrix`, you `order` it using column number.

```
 regional_regression_table[order(regional_regression_table[,2]),]
```